# Grafana Influx Db don't work after update to 1.6.2 version

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, influxdb, grafana

I have my project on GKE and I installed Grafana for getting metrics. After upgrading K8s version to 1.6.2 Grafana stopped to works. I can't see cluster and pods metrics on the dashboard. I can't also see namespaces that I have already set. If I try to access to influxdb via http ( https://X.X.X.X/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb:http/) I got this error `Error: 'ssh: rejected: connect failed (Connection refused)'
Trying to reach: 'http://10.0.7.3:8083/'`. So, if you need some other information, please ask me. Thanks.

Comment: This looks very similar to the https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44275. In the meanwhile, you can try using `kubectl port-forward` to access Grafana service.

Comment: Hi @AhmetAlpBalkan, and thanks for the response. I read that issue and actually, i hade the same problem on my cluster. I solved it using a proxy. My issue is different I guess, I can access to my grafana dashboard but I can't see metrics, pods name or any kind of information about my cluster.